# How do I find the frictional force using a free body diagram?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Body Diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16081/free-body-diagram)

I have this problem:

> A person push a 16 kg lawn mower at constant speed with a force of 80 Newtons directed along the handle which is at an angle of 45 degree to the horizontal. Calculate the force of friction.  Use a free body diagram.

How do I use a free body diagram to solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to google the term, "Mathematical Physics."

Comment: Not mathematical physics, retagged as classical mechanics and homework.